# Android webview how long cookies are saved?

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview

My app saves cookies but deletes them after 2 weeks. I need the data to be stored for a long time. Please help me.

```
public void getWebview(String myurl) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

    });
    webView.loadUrl(myurl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cookies are stored as long as they should, may be even years... but that depend on cookie setting. inspect `Set-Cookie:` header in your request responses and you will find out how long your cookie should be kept by `WebView` (I bet "your" site is setting cookie validity for 2 weeks)

[some article about mechanic of cookie (and its expiration)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/lucky-cookies)